# Magento 2 - Unable to connect on development environment

Tags: magento2, aws

I am facing an issue after changing the permissions on 777 to the var/media files.
I can't connect to the website because the page shows these errors:

[image]

If I try to use PuTTY or Filezilla I get these notifications:

On PuTTY:

> Network error: Software caused connection abort.

On Filezilla:

> Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
>   Error: Could not connect to the server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx...
>   Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>   Command: open "root@xx.xx.xx.xx" 22
>   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>   Error:  Could not connect to the server.

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Add permissions on 755 to the `var/media` files. and check it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but could you tell me how I could to do it, if I can't connect to the server using Putty, Filezilla or other similar software?

Comment: If possible then contact your hosting provider. Or else first try to connect with the server.

Comment: Try to connect with the server using the terminal.

Comment: If I try to connect using the terminal on Putty, after connecting to the bastion host, I receive this message: "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

Comment: Which server you use now?

Comment: I'm using AWS EC2 Instance with Apache Server

Answer (score 0):

did you restart your server? if yes then it changes IP address on each reboot of server so kindly do check updated Private DNS Name and try to connect your server through putty with the same credential, just change new Hostname (DNS Name)

reply to me if you are getting difficulty to find DNS name.

Thanks,
Alpesh